# How to get the coords of browser window when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm try to get the coords of the browser window when the user scroll my page.

Is there's anyway to get window coords with scroll event?.

- When I'm using `mousemove` event it works fine but when I use scroll event it gives me `undefined`.
- I know that mouse events has an event to posibility to using her event with `deltaX` , `clientX` , `pageX` event.

But how to use scroll event to get the coords of and element?

Here's my code
´´´javascript

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",function(e){
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
  console.log(coords);
});
```

´´´

If I change `scroll` to any mouse event like `mousemove` it works fine
but when using scroll it's give me undefined

So i need anything help me to get the coords when the user scrolling my page.

I've tried `scrollHeight`, `deltaX|Y` ,`pageX|Y`and `clientX|Y` but nothing work.

Answer (score 1):

OK, try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>     <title></title> </head> <body>  <div id="res"></div> <script type="text/javascript">

  for (var i = 100; i >= 0; i--) {
    let x = document.createElement("h1");
    x.innerHTML = "just text";
    document.body.append(x)
  }
  
  $(window).scroll(function showCoords(event) {
    console.log(window.scrollY);
  })
  
  </script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="res"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 for (var i = 100; i >= 0; i--) {
  let x = document.createElement("h1");
  x.innerHTML = "just text";
  document.body.append(x)
 }
 $(window).scroll(function showCoords(event) {
            var x = event.pageYOffset;
            var coords = "X coords: " + x;
            console.log(coords);
   })
</script>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: that's my testing page it's also give me undefined you can copy the code and try it

Comment: screenX and pageYOffset are functionally the same as far as I know:
`console.log(window.pageYOffset === window.scrollY)`